# Assigning a value to IEnumerable type of integer

Tags: .net, vb.net, collections, ienumerable

How can I assign a value to the IEnumerable type of integer array in VB.Net?

I need to add the:

```
dim id as integer=obj.id
```

to the array

```
dim arr As IEnumerable(Of Integer)
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean - are you asking to add that value to every item in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. [`IEnumerable(Of T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) does not provide any methods or properties for changing any of the values in the enumeration.

Consider why you think your variable `arr` needs to be of type `IEnumerable`.

- If you get an `IEnumerable` instance from elsewhere, you could add the contents of that enumeration to a [list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) and *then* add additional values to your list.
- Alternatively, even if you want to declare `arr` as `IEnumerable` for some reason, note that you need to instantiate a concrete list class anyway, to which you can add values *before* hiding everything behind the `IEnumerable` interface for later read-only access.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. IEnumerable is an interface, it does not represent a specific class.

Answer (score 1):

The `IEnumerable` is an interface and you cannot init it. You have to instance a concrete type, such as List and keep the declaration with a abstract type like `IEnumerable`. Doing this you can protect the collection from write operations, but when you want to do it, you have to cast the collection to a concrete type that allow you to add, remove values. For sample:

```
'get value
Dim id as Integer = obj.id

' create your collection and init it with a concrete type
Dim arr As IEnumerable(Of Integer) = new List(Of Integer)

'add in your collection
CType(arr, List(Of Integer).Add(id)
```